# g++ unable to link libgsl

Tags: c++, linker, gsl

I try to use the gsl library in one project, but I can't get the example program from the gsl website run properly. The source code and all commands are taken from the website: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Using-the-library.html#Using-the-library

The program is the following (test.cpp):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>

int main (void) {
  double x = 5.0;
  double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
  printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y); 
  return 0;
}
```

Then I first compile without errors. But the linking fails:

```
$ g++ -Wall -I/usr/include/ -c test.cpp
$ g++ -L/usr/lib/ -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm test.o
test.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `gsl_sf_bessel_J0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But the libraries are available:

```
$ ll /usr/lib/libgsl*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Mar  2  2012 /usr/lib/libgsl.so.0 -> libgsl.so.0.16.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Mar  2  2012 /usr/lib/libgsl.so -> libgsl.so.0.16.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Mar  2  2012 /usr/lib/libgslcblas.so.0 -> libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Mar  2  2012 /usr/lib/libgslcblas.so -> libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.3M Mar  2  2012 /usr/lib/libgsl.so.0.16.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 274K Mar  2  2012 /usr/lib/libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 503K Mar  2  2012 /usr/lib/libgslcblas.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.3M Mar  2  2012 /usr/lib/libgsl.a
```

As well as the header files:

```
$ whereis gsl
gsl: /usr/include/gsl /usr/share/man/man3/gsl.3.gz
```

I also tried downloading and installing the lib manually but there is no difference (this one is the Ubuntu package for 12.04 LTS).

/edit2:

Using nm it does not give any further hints:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/libgsl.a
[...]
bessel_J0.o:
00000000000004c0 T gsl_sf_bessel_J0
0000000000000000 T gsl_sf_bessel_J0_e
                 U gsl_sf_bessel_cos_pi4_e
[...]
```

Comment: Have you tracked down which of the files actually provides the symbol `gsl_sf_bessel_J0` ?

Comment: I have the source code from the tgz archive and this function is defined in specfunc/bessel_J0.c. How can I find out to which lib* it compiles? /edit: If I apply 'strings' to the lib files the term `gsl_sf_bessel_J0` occurs in `libgsl.a` and `libgsl.so`

Comment: use tools like `nm` or `objdump`

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I used now nm, but the functions do not refer to anything: `$ nm test.o`: `U gsl_sf_bessel_J0` `0000000000000000 T main` `U printf`

Comment: Ok, I tried also `nm /usr/lib/libgsl.a` and there it refers to the file `bessel_J0.o`

Comment: When you are linking .a archives, make sure your linker lists them in the correct order.

Comment: Ok. I played around a bit with the order, but it didn't change anything. Additionally, the given order is the same as in the tutorial.

Comment: I could reproduce the problem. Caused by "inverting" linking flags. First you write the .o file, then the linking flags

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy fix:

You must link as follows

```
 g++ -L/usr/local/lib/ test.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

You inverted the order while linking (first .o files, then the -l flags)

PS: I could reproduce your problem using your original

```
 g++ -L/usr/local/lib/ -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm test.o
```

and I use gsl all the time without linking problem. I fixed by inverting the order as I said before.

PS2: [image]See picture

Comment: Yes, and that is essentially the same advise as in my earlier answer.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I am so sorry if you already answer it. But I just read your answer again I still could not see that this is your final advice. It was not my intention to duplicate your answer.

Comment: Just look at my link arguments.

Comment: They are correct, but it was not clear to me that you showed him that this was the mistake. Sorry. I should have cited something like "look Dirk answer and you will see that he has the correct link order"

Comment: Don't worry about it -- you high-lighted something correct: Oliver was simply using his tools the wrong way.   He has not bothered to upvote or accept anything, so <shrug>, let's not waste more time here.

Comment: I thought by linking flags you mean the order of the -l*. I didn't pay much attention to the position of the *.o. Both solutions work, thanks for the efforts.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I fixed that sentence to make the meaning more clear.

Comment: This Vivean's answer is much clearer than the @Dirk one and goes straight to the solution of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This works without a hitch on Ubuntu 13.04:

```
edd@max:~/src/progs/C$ cat gsl_bessel.c
// cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588607/g-unable-to-link-libgsl

#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>

int main (void) {
    double x = 5.0;
    double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
    printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y); 
    return 0;
}
edd@max:~/src/progs/C$ gcc -Wall -o gsl_bessel gsl_bessel.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
edd@max:~/src/progs/C$ ./gsl_bessel 
J0(5) = -1.775967713143382642e-01
edd@max:~/src/progs/C$
```

Maybe reinstall / check the packages?  They have not changed in a long while.

(Disclaimer: I happen to be the Debian maintainer behind these packages.)

*Edit:* Oh, re-reading your title and tags, your mistake is the use of `g++` instead of `gcc`.  This is a C library, and you wrote a C program.  It works with C++ but you need `extern "C"` (which is a different topic).

*Edit 2:* Never mind. Works fine with `g++` as well here as the headers are C++ ready:

```
edd@max:~/src/progs/C$ rm ./gsl_bessel
edd@max:~/src/progs/C$ g++ -Wall -o gsl_bessel gsl_bessel.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
edd@max:~/src/progs/C$ ./gsl_bessel 
J0(5) = -1.775967713143382642e-01
edd@max:~/src/progs/C$
```

Comment: Thanks, Dirk. It doesn't make any difference whether I use `g++` or `gcc`. I reinstalled the packages now many times but no change at all.

Comment: I do not have access to an old 12.04 Ubuntu instance, but I have no reason to believe it was broken there either.  Something else is going on which I cannot decipher giving the information you provided.  You don't have a second (local) copy of GSL somewhere, do you?

Comment: Oh, I do, but it I receive the same error message. I downloaded the latest release from their website (version 1.16 from July 2013, [link](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.16.tar.gz)) and did a `./configure --prefix=<localdir> && make && make install`.

Comment: Try `ldd gsl_bessel` ie call ldd on the executable you built, check the libraries it linked against.

Comment: Actually there are only `libgsl.*` and `libgslcblas.*` in the lib folder. Which one do you refer to exactly? `ldd libgsl.so` gives me `linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff0c13c000)`, `libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4a3ac5b000)`, `libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4a3a89c000)`, `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4a3b39d000)`

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I tested it on another system (Debian) and it works well. So I don't know why my system is broken. Anyone has the same experience with Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: I think the problem is much simpler to solver. I could reproduce his problem and I fixed by inverting the order of linking arguments.

Answer (score 1):

GSL linking on Windows:

```
gcc -c test.c -Wall -I"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\include"  -o test.o -L"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\lib" -lgslcblas -lgsl -lm

gcc -o test.exe test.o -L"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\lib" -lgslcblas -lgsl -lm
```

where C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\include" is location of include directory in GSL and "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\lib" is location of lib directory.